# How do I iterate through an array when trying to assign cells to certain sections in a UICollectionView in Swift?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm trying to iterate through an array using a for statement inside of the cellForItemAt function. I'm having trouble though because I need to have a return statement exist outside of the for statement, but I'm not sure how to do this properly while still being able to iterate through my task array to ensure only tasks for the proper dates get added to the proper sections. In it's current state, a plain taskCell is getting returned, which I expect to happen - I just did this to silence the error.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let taskCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "taskCellID", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell

    let currentDate = Date()

    let day = DateComponents(calendar: nil, timeZone: nil, era: nil, year: nil, month: nil, day: indexPath.section, hour: nil, minute: nil, second: nil, nanosecond: nil, weekday: nil, weekdayOrdinal: nil, quarter: nil, weekOfMonth: nil, weekOfYear: nil, yearForWeekOfYear: nil)

    let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: day, to: currentDate)

    for task in 0...(userTasks.count - 1) {
        if userTasks[task].dueDate == date {
            taskCell.myTask = userTasks[indexPath.item]
            return taskCell
        }
    }

    return taskCell
}
```

Comment: Create an an array of `userTasks` that corresponds one-to-one to your cells _before_ you load your collection view.

Comment: Oh duh...thank you. So would I then need to create subarrays for each of the possible sections? There are only 7 sections, but that seems pretty redundant. @AshleyMills

Comment: Correct. It may seem redundant, but it’s the right way to do it